# Nesting if statements with Jade

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am finding it difficult to put into words, but how can I use an if statement inside jade and have it only wrap some elements if set to true.

**Mixin**

```
mixin select(data){
    if(!data.small)
        .form-group
    select
        option jamie
```

**Desired**

```
//scss
+select()
//html output
<div class="form-group">
    <select>
        <option>jamie</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Current output**

```
//scss
+select()
//html output
<div class="form-group">
</div>  
<select>
    <option>jamie</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So `if(!data.small)` you want `<div.form-group><select></select></div>` but `if(!!data.small)` you just want `<select></select>`? Or could it still be that div surrounds the select but it doesn't have the class i.e. `<div><select></select></div>`? In other words: is your main issue with whether the div surrounds or not, or whether div has a specific class or not?

Comment: Class is unimportant. The main this is having `<div><select></select></div>` when `data.small` and when `!data.small` to output just the `select` box. I think thats it ye :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two mixins: one for select, another for conditionally surrounding that select.

```
mixin select(data)
    select
        option jamie

mixin surroundingDiv(data)
    if(!data.small)
        .form-group
            mixing select(data)
    else
        mixing select(data)
```